# Are these two extensionality-axioms equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, relations, axioms

Let $\epsilon$ be a binary relation on a set $U$.

A subset $A \subseteq U$ is called **$\epsilon$-transitive** iff
$$a \mathrel{\epsilon} b \wedge b \in A \Rightarrow a \in A$$
for all $a,b \in U$. For $a \in U$ we define the **transitive closure** $T_\epsilon(a) \subseteq U$ of $a$ as the smallest $\epsilon$-transitive superset of $\{x \in U; x \mathrel{\epsilon} a\}$. Further we say that $a,b \in U$ are **$\epsilon$-isomorphic** iff there exists an isomorphism
$$\varphi : (T_\epsilon(a) \cup \{a\},\epsilon) \to (T_\epsilon(b) \cup \{b\},\epsilon)$$
with $\varphi(a) = b $.

---

> **Axiom 1**:
>
> If $a,b \in U$ are $\epsilon$-isomorphic, then $a = b$.

and

> **Axiom 2**:
>
> If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $U$ such that
>   $$[a]_\sim = [b]_\sim \quad\Rightarrow\quad \{[x]_\sim; x \in U, x \mathrel{\epsilon} a\} = \{[y]_\sim; y \in U, y \mathrel{\epsilon} b\}$$
>   for all $a,b \in U$, then $\sim$ has to be the equality $=$.

---

**Question:** Are these axioms equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Axiom 2 is much stronger than Axiom 1.  For instance, consider $U=\{0,1\}$ with $\epsilon={\leq}$.  This satisfies Axiom 1 but fails Axiom 2 because the equivalence relation with one equivalence class satisfies the condition in Axiom 2.  Indeed, the equivalence relation with one equivalence class will be a counterexample to Axiom 2 for any $(U,\epsilon)$ that has no "empty" element.

Comment: You can just add in an empty element and the equivalence relation that identifies $0$ and $1$ is still a counterexample.

Comment: And if I assume that $\epsilon$ is well-founded?

Comment: Then both axioms are equivalent to ordinary extensionality (for Axiom 2, prove that $[a]_{\sim}=\{a\}$ by $\epsilon$-induction on $a$).

Comment: It's obviously not equivalent to well-foundedness.  I would suggest you actually try and think about some examples before you ask more questions.